# Converting POSTMAN request to proper one

Tags: ruby, aem, postman

I am writing a script in Ruby that posts a path, include and exclude filter to Adobe CQ CMS. I was initially having problems posting the filters with the request. So, I ran the request through POSTMAN and after it was successfull I copied the request and used it in my script. But, since it is not the right way of doing things. I am looking for some help with converting this POSTMAN request into a proper one.

Here is the function:

```
def postFilter(postURL,excludeRule,includeRule, auth_code)
  url = URI(postURL)

  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
  request["content-type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  request["authorization"] = "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
  request["cache-control"] = "no-cache"
  request.body = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rules\"\r\n\r\n#{excludeRule}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rules\"\r\n\r\n#{includeRule}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"

  response = http.request(request)
end
```

I have another problem: Right now the password is hardcoded (Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=). I tried eliminating this by passing password as an arguement to the function but it didn't work. I am not able to figure out if there is a semantics error or logical error.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For authentication you can use Ruby's built in `basic_auth` method.

replace this:

```
request["authorization"] = "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
```

with

```
request.basic_auth(username, password)
```

read about it here https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: Thanks. This helped me :).